# Gradle, different "platform(" or not?

Tags: android, gradle

Android pros, I had an interesting thing where this:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore')
```

does not work.  Whereas this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
```

works fine.

I do have

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
```

up top in both cases.

What is the difference / meaning of the "platform(" .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A platform is a special kind of software component which doesn’t
> contain any sources: it is only used to reference other libraries, so
> that they play well together during dependency resolution.

From Docs: [https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#:~:text=A%20platform%20is%20a%20special%20kind%20of%20software,published%20as%20Gradle%20Module%20Metadata%20and%20Maven%20BOMs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#:%7E:text=A%20platform%20is%20a%20special%20kind%20of%20software,published%20as%20Gradle%20Module%20Metadata%20and%20Maven%20BOMs).

With "platform" you can introduce maven bills of material, which means you only want to get the dependencies of this dependency without itself being a jar for example. This is also the reason why without the platform keyword it does not work.